# Problems with no signal amp

Tags: amplifier, audio, noise

I am making a project witch have processing of an audio signal with a microcontroller. This signal I filter and then I need to play in a speaker. Because I don't have many experience with amps and audio, I make the easy way and I bought module to amplify the signal. What I have is an TDA2030 with simple supply (12V).

The problem is when I put 0V on the input of the amplifier (I also tried putting the input to ground directly) the speaker makes noise. I really don't understand why this happen and I tried many things to solved it.
I also tried to make a circuit that powers off the amp which work fine, but now I have a pop noise because of the power off/on which also is annoying
I know I could put a relay to the output of the amp but this is my last choice, anyone have a better idea?

I added an oscilloscope image of the output of the speaker when I short to ground the input.

[image]

So i do inverse ingeenering and the circuit is excatly like the datasheet sugest although i could not find out what capacitors are because they are smd. And the input potenciometer in my case is 1k.

[image]

And as you guys said to me I change the supply, because is one that i made in my secondary (i think it wasnt to good) and used insted an YIHUA1502D (economical linear power supply) and all the problems disapeared.

So now i have new questions, What i need to prevent things like this to happen? I mean my previus power supply was regulated by an LM7805 and "i think" that it is not a switching one.
Also some of you ask if i have 50hz line and the answer is yes, i think you come to this because de 100hz of the signal (make some sence now).

Thanks a lot for your comments they really help me :)

Comment: Please provide a schematic and parameters of your setup including the power supply. Ground loop problems and grid interference as we see here, can only be solved if we see the whole wiring.

Comment: A photo of the setup might help too. What frequency is the AC mains in your area? Exactly what 12V power supply are you using?

Comment: Is the power supply by any chance a linear power supply and do you happen to live in a country with 50Hz mains frequency?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but i was really bussy this days. I edit the post so all of your asks are answerd. Again thanks for your time